# Spaces / align of variable definitions in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

I have this:

```
    $accountNr = $csvData[2][1];
$firstname = $csvData[3][1];
$lastname = $csvData[4][1];
$telephone1 = $csvData[5][1];
$telephone2 = $csvData[6][1];
$telephone3 = $csvData[7][1];
$telephone4 = $csvData[8][1];
$email1 = $csvData[9][1];
$email2 = $csvData[10][1];
$email3 = $csvData[11][1];
$email4 = $csvData[12][1];
$address1 = $csvData[13][1];
$address2 = $csvData[14][1];
$zip = $csvData[15][1];
$state = $csvData[16][1];
```

I want this:

```
$accountNr  = $csvData[2][1];
$firstname  = $csvData[3][1];
$lastname   = $csvData[4][1];
$telephone1 = $csvData[5][1];
$telephone2 = $csvData[6][1];
$telephone3 = $csvData[7][1];
$telephone4 = $csvData[8][1];
$email1     = $csvData[9][1];
$email2     = $csvData[10][1];
$email3     = $csvData[11][1];
$email4     = $csvData[12][1];
$address1   = $csvData[13][1];
$address2   = $csvData[14][1];
$zip        = $csvData[15][1];
$state      = $csvData[16][1];
```

There is a IntelliJ plugin called "String Manipulation" that does exactly that.

But: when I select the whole file and format it using the formatting of PhpStorm, everything gets changed again.

Is there a different cleaner way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. `Settings/Preferences`
2. `Editor | Code Style | PHP`
3. `Wrapping and Braces --> Assignment statement`
4. Activate `Align consecutive assignments` option

[image]