# IntelliJ plugin for aligning multiline arrays visually while keeping the code only single spaced

Tags: phpstorm, text-alignment, intellij-plugin

I'm using PhpStorm and was wondering if there's a plugin that will align multiline arrays and even possibly multiple consecutive assignments visually  but will keep the code with only a single space before and after the `=>` or `=`.

I know that there's an option to [literally align those built in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39283900/spaces-align-of-variable-definitions-in-intellij), but as with many companies we have a debate on the subject and I, with others, want to enforce a single space before and after the items at all times for less code changes in code reviews and to preserve git history.

So an example:

This is what the the actual code would look like:

```
$a = [
    'key1' => 'value1',
    'key2' => 'value2',
    'longkey3' => 'value3',
];
$b = 1;
$longc = 2;

$key_after_new_line = 3;
```

But as far as what it would look like in PhpStorm this is what it would be:

```
$a     = [
    'key1'     => 'value1',
    'key2'     => 'value2',
    'longkey3' => 'value3',
];
$b     = 1;
$longc = 2;

$key_after_new_line = 3;
```

Comment: I don't understand. What do you want aligned, exactly? In the first sample you posted, I don't see anything aligned except the start of the array keys, which IntelliJ should align by default.

Comment: @Jeto He wants code to stay formatted like #1 (especially when saved in the file) ... but when editing the same code should be formatted like #2 for convenience. So it's like virtual formatting for edit time only. Or, in other words (another approach), different Code Style gets applied when editing and when saving to file.

Comment: @LazyOne Oh, I see. Well, since Will's using Git, it might be achievable via the [Command Line Formatter](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/command-line-formatter.html) and pre-commit hooks (formatting would happen on commits instead of saves though, which would also be fine I suppose).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, there's no plugin for that currently, but the feature request is sitting there for a while no: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-534